# Removing Dialog pop-up message on link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

So I added this JavaScript for my `<select> <option>` dropdowns to redirect to their value attribute.

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("a").click(function(event) {
          alert(event.target.id);
    });

    $(document).on('change', '#selectdrops', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        menu_goto(e.target.value);
    });
    })

    function menu_goto( newurl ) {
    var baseurl = window.document.location.protocol + '//' + window.document.location.host;

    if (newurl.length != 0) {
        window.location = baseurl + newurl ;
    }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="newurl" class="mobile about-drop" id="selectdrops">
      <option id="sec-1" value="/content/7-about">The Families</option>
      <option id="sec-2" class="active" value="/content/4-the-farm">The Farm</option>
      <option id="sec-3" value="/content/8-viniculture">Viniculture</option>
    </select>
```

I had to focus on using the ID's becuase prestashop CMS source code does not allow any type of JavaScript.

This method worked 100% and I'm happy with using it, I have only one problem.

**Problem:**

This drop down is only used for mobile and for desktop I use a simple `<ul>` with `<li>`s linked to their corresponding pages. But suddenly now when I click on any link (desktop version, not the drop down mobile links) I get this dialog message where I first have to click 'ok' before my page redirects to the corresponding url.

How to remove this message from all the desktop links?

ps: on mobile it's fine, and clicking on the mobile dropdown link redirects without any dialog pop-ups.

Comment: what dialog popup you gets on desktop?

Comment: are you getting an alert? you added `click` event listener to all your anchor tags in `$document.ready()`. Consider adding event listener to menu links only?

Comment: i get what you are saying @azs06 but then how would i do that... changing the "a" tag to select what specifically ?

Comment: your first click event listener doesn't seem to be doing anything except alert, consider removing it? try removing first `$(document).ready`.

Comment: thank you @azs06, worked,marked-up your answer!